# My Reactive Form doesn't display nothing in html. My value show in console

Tags: angular, forms, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, form-control

I have the problem with my form. 
Firstly I create a simple form for create a product. This product are like this:

```
Description:"fff"
Line_num:"4"
Quantity:545
Subtotal:3027475
Unit_price:5555
product_id:"11E826CB009A1864B430FA163EBBBC1D"
product_type_id:"11E7FC041F467AD4B09D00FF76874A55"
```

Secondly, I create a formgroup addsale, wherein I put my product value, and add some another value. 
In this component ts, I call product from this code,   `this.products = this.ps.getProduct();` this code show up in console log value.

This is my form in ts:

```
  this.addsale = new FormGroup({
          'invoice_number': new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.nullValidator]),
          'invoice_date': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
          'client_id': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
          'amount_paid': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
          'notes': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
          'Subtotal': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
          'products': new FormArray([ ]),
          'total': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
          'contactNo': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
          'address': new FormControl('', Validators.required)
        });
```

In html I used this code:

```
<form [formGroup]="addsale" (ngSubmit)="onaddsale()">
    <tbody formArrayName="products">
      <tr class="form-group" style="cursor: pointer" *ngFor="let item of addsale.get('products').controls; index as i">
        <td>
          <input   formControlName="Unit_price" type="number">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input   formControlName="Quantity" type="number">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input  formControlName="Description" type="text" name="Description">
        </td>
        <td>

         <input  formControlName="Subtotal" readonly type="number"> 
        </td>
        <td>
          <button type="button" class="fa" (click)="onRemoveItem(i)">x</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</form>
```

This code, in consloe show up me all correctly value, but in html doesn't show nothing.

Please can you help me, how to solution this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see in your example, you are not defining your `FormArray`. You are declaring it in your `FormGroup`, but not defining the `FormControls` that are in the `FormArray`.

Mine looks like this:

```
    this.customerForm = this.fb.group({
        firstName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
        lastName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)]],
        emailGroup: this.fb.group({
            email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+')]],
            confirmEmail: ['', Validators.required],
        }, {validator: emailMatcher}),
        phone: '',
        notification: 'email',
        rating: ['', ratingRange(1, 5)],
        sendCatalog: true,
        addresses: this.fb.array([this.buildAddress()])
    });
```

Notice that I'm passing a method in to the FormArray to define its layout.

That method looks like this:

```
buildAddress(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
            addressType: 'home',
            street1: '',
            street2: '',
            city: '',
            state: '',
            zip: ''
    });
}
```

Then it is *these* FormControl names that have to be bound to the formControlName property ... not the names of the product properties.

You can find this and several more complete form examples here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular2-ReactiveForms